# $(window).load(function() inside a statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure if I can have  $(window).load(function() inside a statement? Is this correct?

```
    else if (isAndroid){ 
      $('.apple, .bottomcta, .bottomapple, .cta, .cta2').hide(); 
      $('.android').show(); 


      $(window).load(function() { 

    if ($('.yes2, .YES2').css('display') == 'none') { 
      $('#bottombadge > p, #badge > p, .bottomandroid, .android, .bottomapple, .apple').remove(); 
      $('#button, .cta, .bottomcta').show(); 
      } 

    else if ($('.no, .NO').css('display') == 'block') { 
      $('.bottomapple, .apple').remove();
      }                                          

      }
      );

    }
```

Any thoughts please?

Comment: I think there won't be any errors but the code never gets executed because the page should have allready been loaded.

Comment: What is purpose of `.load()` call? Is the call necessary to perform tasks within `else..if`? Which version of jQuery is being used?

Comment: Thanks. I'm using 2.1.1 I have various statements. The statements that I have another statement within it, doesn't work properly. 
            if (isiPhone > -1) { 
              $('.apple, .bottomapple, #bottombagde').show(); 
              $('.android, .cta, .bottomcta, .bottomandroid').remove();  
             
              if ($('.yes, .YES').css('display') == 'none') {  
              $('.cta, .cta2, .bottomcta').show(); } 
               
            }

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it.

After all, you are just using jQuery to attach an event handler to the `load` event of the `window` object.

But, it is not so useful because, as @Siphalor has commented:

> the code never gets executed because the page should have allready
>   been loaded

Instead, you should do something like:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    if (isAndroid){ 
         $('.apple, .bottomcta, .bottomapple, .cta, .cta2').hide(); 
         $('.android').show(); 
         // more code
```

Comment: Thanks. My code runs fine without $(window).load(function() until there's a statement inside another:
            else if (isiPhone > -1){ 
              $('.apple, .bottomapple, #bottombagde').show(); 
              $('.android, .cta, .bottomcta, .bottomandroid').remove();  
                
              if ($('.yes, .YES').css('display') == 'none') {  
              $('.cta, .cta2, .bottomcta').show(); } 
            }